# How to add a word at the end of each element of a list?

Tags: python, list

I have the list:

```
mylist = ["all dogs go", "why does one", "fell down so hard I"]
```

Is there a function that will allow me to add the word `"moo"` to the end of each element in `mylist`?

Comment: Can you please provide desired output to clarify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to do that:

```
>>> mylist = ["all dogs go", "why does one", "fell down so hard I"]
>>> mylist = [x + " moo" for x in mylist]
>>> mylist
['all dogs go moo', 'why does one moo', 'fell down so hard I moo']
```

That creates a new list, so you can also use a for loop to do the same (which changes existing list object, though that shouldn't really matter in small examples like this one):

```
>>> mylist
['all dogs go', 'why does one', 'fell down so hard I']
>>> for idx in xrange(len(mylist)):
...     mylist[idx] = mylist[idx] + " moo"
... 
>>> mylist
['all dogs go moo', 'why does one moo', 'fell down so hard I moo']
```

---

As for your edited question, you could use the below if your pattern is valid for all elements:

```
>>> mylist = ["8 - 9 -", "7 - 6 -", "5 - 4 -"]
>>> mylist = [x[:-1] for x in mylist]
>>> mylist
['8 - 9 ', '7 - 6 ', '5 - 4 ']
```

Answer (score 7):

Use list comprehensions:

```
>>> mylist[:] = [word.strip() + " moo" for word in mylist]
>>> print mylist
['all dogs go moo', 'why does one moo', 'fell down so hard I moo']
```

Answer (score 1):

just use `append`:

```
mylist.append('moo')
>>> mylist
['all dogs go', 'why does one', 'fell down so hard I', 'moo']
```

EDIT:

If you want to append 'moo' to EACH element in your list, use the suggestion by @mu (no pun intended).  Sorry @ozgur, I didn't intentionally leave you out, the pun was intended...

Comment: mu 無, and ozgur's method was what I was looking for but thanks for replying.

Comment: Here's a +1 for the pun :)