# How to replace elements in a list using a For Loop

Tags: python, list

How to add 'ing' to each verb in my list `verbs`?  If I was to append each word with "ing" such as "kayaking, crying..." to a new list then that's easy but I can't figure out how to overwrite the original verbs list with "kayaking, crying, walking..."

I don't believe **append** would be the right method since that's just going to add each **words** object to the end of the verbs list. Thank you all.

```
verbs = ["kayak", "cry", "walk", "eat", "drink", "fly"]

for words in verbs:
    words = words + "ing"
```

Comment: in python we mostly create new list with new elements and later we assing to old variable - and we use `append()` or list comprehension.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a word at the end of each element of a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31978934/how-to-add-a-word-at-the-end-of-each-element-of-a-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you specifically need to use a for loop the easiest way to do this is to use an index for the list as follows:

```
for i in range(len(verbs)):
    verbs[i] += 'ing'
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. We are learning the accumulator pattern so this works perfectly. Thank you for the explanation Paula!

Answer (score 10):

You can use list comprehension:

```
verbs = ["kayak", "cry", "walk", "eat", "drink", "fly"]
verbs = [words + "ing" for words in verbs]
```

Comment: This is a cool technique and we haven't learned this yet. I hope we eventually learn this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
verbs = ["kayak", "cry", "walk", "eat", "drink", "fly"] #given list

ing=[] #creates an empty dictionary named ing

for words in verbs: #it will iterate through every items in verbs 
    #print(words)
    ing.append(words+'ing') #concatenation of strings. two strings are added
          #.append is an attribute to list to add an item in the list.
print (ing) #finally we get the output
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 0):

```
verbs = ["kayak", "cry", "walk", "eat", "drink", "fly"]
ing=[]
for i in range(len(verbs)):
    ing.append(verbs[i]+"ing")

print(ing)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please consider adding some explanation/comments to your code.